# How can I run Digikam after installing it?

Tags: 10.04, software-center, package-management, photo-management, digikam

I have installed Digikam in the Software Center on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system but I cannot find it. I have checked out Applications but it is not there. I know I have it because when I view the installed packages in the Ubuntu Software Center it is listed as being installed.

Comment: Try to run it from terminal, In terminal type `digikam` and hit `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it should be listed under `Applications > Graphics >`

[image]

But if for some reason its not then you can create a custom desktop launcher/shortcut for it.

- Right click on your desktop and click `Create Launcher`. and fill it out as follow.

  ```
  Type:        Application
  Name:        Digikam
  Command:     digikam -caption "%c" %i
  Comments:    Manage your photographs like a professional with the power of open source
  ```
- Click OK. That's it!

You can also launch Digikam from terminal:

- To open terminal hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:
- ```
  digikam
  ```

  OR (If you want to keep the terminal usable to run other commands)
- ```
  digikam &
  ```

Or from Run command:

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, Type `digikam` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Please note that while the ` &` at the end of the `digikam` command in the Terminal will make it so that Terminal window/tab remains usable to run other commands while Digikam is running, Digikam will quit abruptly if the shell running in the Terminal is exited (which happens when the Terminal, or that tab/window, is closed). Some users may prefer to run it without the `&` operator, so it's clear that Terminal is in use and shouldn't be closed.

Comment: Thank you, I loaded the program from the terminal as you suggested.

Comment: @EliahKagan Updated. You're are welcome George.